# Avoiding double calculation in PostgreSQL and PostGIS for improved performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, spatial

PostgreSQL / PostGIS example with double calculation:

```
select a.gid, b.gid, st_area(st_intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) from a_polygons a, b_polygons b 
where st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom) and st_area(st_intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) > 10;
```

Is there some simple way in such cases to avoid double (multiple) calculation of the same value?

I know I could achieve it like this:

```
with i_poly as (select a.gid a_gid, b.gid b_gid, st_area(st_intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) i_area  
from a_polygons a, b_polygons b where st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom))
select a_gid, b_gid, i_area from i_poly where i_area > 10;
```

Is there any simple way to achieve it without with, sub-queries etc.? Something as simple as:

```
 select i_area from a_polygons a, b_polygons b where st_area(st_intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) as i_area > 10;
```

Comment: Does the plan tell you it's calculated twice? SQL is declarative, generally you leave it up to the engine to figure out an expression is used once...

Comment: The st_area(..) should only be calculated once. Expressions can often be “shared” between the select/where/order by..

Comment: @ta.speot.is I admit I have no idea how to figure that out.

Comment: @user2864740 How do I know for sure?

Comment: And besides, what is the problem with subqueries?

Comment: Miro: the query plan.. the SQL engine is free to (and often does, to different extents) “rewrite” queries. This too can be viewed in the plan.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe my understanding is sub-queries might produce big amounts of temporary data which might be problematic, and take significantly longer to process than doing the same thing in one go if possible.

Comment: @user2864740 How exactly I do that? I am looking at PostgreSQL doc, on EXPLAIN and all the options starting ANALYZE and can't find "rewritten" query. Time wise the query runs about twice as long if I select the area value over the query, where I select only ids. So I presume it is calculated twice.

Comment: Your understanding is not accurate. Subqueries don't have to be materialized. Look at the execution plan for a "Materialize" node.

Answer (score 0):

Move the polygon calculations to the `from` clause:

```
select a.gid, b.gid, a.area
from a_polygons a cross join
     b_polygons b cross join lateral
     (values (st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom)) i(intersect) cross join lateral
     (values (st_area(i.intersect))) a(area)
where i.intersect and a.area > 10;
```